# How to Avoid Installing or Deploying a Test Only Module in Maven

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing, git-submodules

In a multimodule Maven project I have some integration tests that run after everything else has built and depend on all other modules. These are in a module called integration-tests. The whole module is just tests though, nothing else. I don't want this installed to the local repository or deployed. I don't even need it packaged.

How can I disable the install and deploy lifecycle phases for this submodule only? (Or make them no-ops with no goals.)

That is, I want to type `mvn clean install` from the root directory and have the tests execute and the build fail if they fail. However if the build succeeds, I don't want an integration-tests module to be placed in my local repo. All other modules should be installed like normal.

Answer (score 0):

One way I could think of is to set the `skip` parameter of the install and deploy plugin to true (in the POM of this module).